# How do I fill these kind of holes and make the object flat, not round?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

Trying to make a surface of holes with the *Array* modifier and the *Subdivision Surface* modifier but the *Array* modifier does not merge the copies and the *Subdivision Surface* modifier makes the outside round which I need straight.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Frequently the order of the modifiers is important.  In this case, the Subdivision modifier should be after the Array modifiers:

[image]

If the four rounded outside corners are a problem then after the Array modifiers are applied supporting geometry should be created.